# press button: servo move - hold X time - move back issue

Tags: arduino-uno, servo

Besides being a total noob I've been lurking and reading like mad over the last week to understand how to get my servo to move to X position when a button is pushed, have it wait Y time, and return to the starting position.  I've come up with this code but could use some guidance.

```
#include <Servo.h>

const int buttonPin = 8;
const int servoPin = 9;
int buttonState = 0;
int directionState = 0;
Servo servoOne;
int pos = 0;

void setup() {
  servoOne.attach(9);
  servoOne.write(directionState);
  pinMode(buttonPin, INPUT);
}

void loop() {
  buttonState = digitalRead(buttonPin);
  if (directionState == 0) {
    if (buttonState == HIGH) {
      directionState = 1;
      for (pos = 0; pos < 180; pos = pos + 1) {
        servoOne.write(pos);
        delay(5);
      }
    }
  } else if (directionState == 1) {
    delay(5000); {
      directionState = 0;
      for (pos = 180; pos > 1; pos = pos - 1) {
        servoOne.write(pos);
        delay(5);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Besides an unnecessary  pair of curly brackets after the `delay(5000)` I don't see any obvious errors. What exactly is the problem with your current code? You wrote that you need guidance, but you didn't explain with what.

Comment: You should be more precise. What do you expect your code to do and what does it instead? A state machine is probably the simplest way to implement what you need, but for a user behaving appropriately I would expect your code to work